# Write an NSString in a CGContext gives is always in black

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstring, cgcontext, uicolor

I try to write an NSString in a Context but am unable to set its color ; it always appears in black:

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 200));
   [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
   [@"Hello" drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, theStringSize.width, theStringSize.height) withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSFontAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Italic" size:12],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIColor whiteColor], nil]];
   MyImgView.image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What am I missing to set my text in white ?
 Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you put Keys then Objects/value instead of Objects/Value, then Key => `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Optima-Italic" size:12],NSFontAttributeName,[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]`

Comment: That was so easy.Oops, didn't know that. And indeed, inverting values makes it work, thanks !!